# Is it possible to check if a polygon intersects with itself using Clipper?

Tags: intersection, polygons, clipperlib

Can I use Clipper to check if my polygon contour intersects with itself (if it is  a complex or a simple polygon)?

I know that it does not make the polygon invalid, but in my case I want to avoid self intersecting polygons.

Comment: No, there's no function for that in the library.

Comment: Ok you can post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no function for that in the library.